# Can't Add Object to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class called `KCBlackjack`. The class contains this code:

```
playerHand = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dealerHand = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

blackjack = [[KCBlackjack alloc] initWithNumberOfDecks:6];
[self deal];

[blackjack dealTo:playerHand dealer:dealerHand];
```

---

```
- (void)dealTo:(NSMutableArray *)player dealer:(NSMutableArray *)dealer {
    // How many cards are left
    NSLog(@"Cards in Deck: %d", [_decks count]);

    // Deal to player then dealer
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        [player addObject:[_decks lastObject]];
        [_decks removeLastObject];

        NSLog(@"%@", player);

        if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDistributeCard:withValue:)]) {
            KCCard *aCard = (KCCard *)[player objectAtIndex:player.count-1];
            [_delegate didDistributeCard:aCard to:player withValue:[aCard value]];
        }

        [dealer addObject:[_decks lastObject]];
        [_decks removeLastObject];

        NSLog(@"%@", dealer);

        if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDistributeCard:withValue:)]) {
            KCCard *aCard = (KCCard *)[dealer objectAtIndex:dealer.count-1];
           [_delegate didDistributeCard:aCard to:dealer withValue:[aCard value]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Done Dealing");

    NSLog(@"Cards Remaining in Deck: %d", [_decks count]);

    NSLog(@"Player: %@\n\n", player);
    NSLog(@"Dealer: %@\n\n", dealer);
}
```

Inside of my game controller, I set `player` to my player array as well as the dealer his. When this is run however, it doesn't work. No objects are added to the player array that player or dealer is assigned.

When the code is in the game controller, it works, but not in this class. I figure something is not initializing, but in the game controller, the player and dealer are both initialized.

Comment: check you have initialized the NSMutableArray in this class.

Comment: Which class? My KCBlackjack or the Game View Controller?

Comment: Could you be more explicit in which parts aren't working? When you add a breakpoint/NSLog after you add the object to your player array, does it actually add the [_decks lastObject]?

Comment: @Lucas Yes it does, but not to playerHand.

Comment: My suggestion is to nslog the arrays at every step to see what is and what is not being added, also ensure they are all mutable arrays, and that you are not logging nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of it from a OO perspective, dealer and player are really objects that should receive a message such as addCardToHand:(Card *)aCard. The way you are doing it, Lucas has exactly right, you get a copy of his array which is not mutable. I'd much rather see some dot notation such as player.hand addCard:(Card*)aCard if you don't want the player to handle the card himself (watch for card sharps! :-)  ).

I think if you refactor with objects you can have clean code that works, and probably get rid of that delegation stuff (which is a bit confusing just reading).

Good luck - blackjack is fun!

Damien

Comment: I actually found out it was going to the playerHand the whole time! But when I put in a delegate, it changed my card animations and they never showed. Problem is solved and delegate works great! Thanks.

Comment: Ya I didn't properly look at the question and I forgot that an NSMutableArray was being passed in, which will be affected by messages sent to that object in the method. If it were just an NSArray then it would be changed to a different address if it were set to something else.

Comment: Thanks Lucas for helping me out.

Comment: @AlecK. Not a problem, glad you figured it out on your own.